# Export of site fails in every attempt

Tags: error, stsadm

I am trying to export one of my sites, but whatever I do it keeps giving me the error: **The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.**

```
stsadm -o export -url http://server/site/ -filena
me D:\test\test.cab -nologfile -nofilecompression
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify *only the folder* for the filename parameter. [To quote MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262759%28office.12%29.aspx):

> **filename** : Name of the export file. *If using the –nofilecompression parameter, a directory must be specified*; otherwise, any file format is valid.

In your sample you seem to use the nofilecompression switch - in that case the export process would produce a set of files and store them in the specified folder. You can either:

- remove the parameter so that the export outputs only one file or
- modify the filename to include only the folder

Note also that the first option would usualy require more time (compression will slow down the export process - but it sure is easier to store only a file).

Answer (score 0):

Is the http://server/site link right? Does it link to the exact site or subsite you want to export?  Try removing the `-nologfile` switch to see what if it generates any errors in the log file.  You are logged into the WFE with a farm admin account correct?

As a general rule of thumb for my exports, I also inclde the `-cabsize 1023` and `-versions 4` switches, not that those would impact this issue.

The d drive location is accessible?  It it's a location the farm admin account has access to?

Comment: the url checks out fine. i have tried removing the -nologfile param but i still get that error. I've tried applying every possible param and i still get that error despite even being logged on with the farm admin account

Comment: additional things added to the question